# using file reader state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have the following piece of code in my app:

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);


 const onHandleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      console.log("e.target.result", e.target.result);
      setFiles(e.target.result);
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
  });
```

I then pass `onHandleChange` to a component that I import using:

```
<Sidebar onSave={onSave} onRestore={onRestore} onReset={onReset} setElements={setElements} removeElements = {removeElements} onDownload={onDownload} 
               onHandleChange={onHandleChange}/>
```

However, the `JSON.stringify` gives me a null. I'm not quite sure why. I know the file is read because the console.log shows me the JSON I uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React `this.setState`, and `useState` does not make changes directly to the state object.

React `this.setState`, and `React.useState` create queues for React core to update the state object of a React component.

So the process to update React state is asynchronous for performance reasons. That’s why changes don’t feel immediate.

For more help [why react setstate usestate does not update immediately](https://linguinecode.com/post/why-react-setstate-usestate-does-not-update-immediately)

```
function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);

  const onHandleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(e.target.files[0], "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = e => {
      setFiles(e.target.result);
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files)); //you can't use the files state here
  });

  console.log(files, 'files'); //  here you will get console
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='file' onChange={(e) => onHandleChange(e)} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: But even if I move the console.log up a into the .onload function (right after setFiles) it still doesn't work. Or is it asynchronous even to that level?

How would I change it if I wanted to wait?

Comment: Set `files` this variable in `render` method !

Comment: @user1357015 Upadate my answer pls check